# SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 is not working, even though Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is installed?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-ce-4

I already have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed. I am using express edition. Also, installed SQL CE 4.0 runtime, which eventually repair what is installed. Now, in my installed program list in control panel, SQL CE 4.0 is showing up. But when I am trying to add that in Project, its Just not showing up in list of new item. And problem is that, SQL CE 3.5 also stops working. I seriously don't know what to do. I am also trying, but if anyone know please help me out... I tried almost every option shown in different stack overflow post.

I have checked for Visual Studio Pro/Ultimate version, it is showing up there, but still there is not luck for express edition. And also I am unable to make connection with database, it is not showing in dialog of database provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CE 4.0 is only supported with Web Projects, so install Web Dev Express. You must also install the SQL CE 4.0 Tools for VS 2010 SP1 - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with Windows Application. Back to square one :), same old MDF file again. Hey, do you have any suggestion for light weight database for windows application ??

Comment: Yes!  Thank you - the standalone viewer is perfect for me.